# parseInt()/parseFloat() to ignore non-numeric arguments

Tags: javascript

How can I get non-numeric arguments to be ignored with parseInt or parseFloat in the following function?

```
 function highestNumber(num1, num2, num3) {
      var highest = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
      return highest;
 }

 alert(highestNumber(26,1,109));
```

Comment: So if it's not a number type you want to exclude it from Math.max()?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `parseInt` or `parseFloat` are of any use here. You can simply test whether a value is a number and [filter out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) all non-number values:

```
return Math.max.apply(Math, Array.prototype.filter.call(arguments, function(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number';
}));
```

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an *array-like* object which contains all arguments passed to the function. But since it isn't an actual array, we have to use [`Array.prototype.<method>.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to use an array method on it.

[`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) lets you call a function with an unknown number of parameters by just passing an array as second argument.

---

If you want to allow numeric strings, e.g. `"123"`, you can use `isNaN` instead (and some extra guards against `null` and empty string):

```
return Math.max.apply(Math, Array.prototype.filter.call(arguments, function(value) {
    return value != null && value !== "" && !isNaN(value);
}));
```

Why extra tests for `null` and `""`? Because `Number("")` and `Number(null)` return `0`, so `isNaN` will return `false` for both (but we still want to exclude those values).

Comment: Nice answer, but it would be nicer if you explained it. It took me more read-throughs than I'd have liked.